# using ngx-monaco-editor in angular app results in 404

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, monaco-editor

I am trying to use the editor in my Angular 8 app. Note: The exact same error was listed in one of the SO questions, but the answer was not there. I have gone through GIT discussions on this issue, but still the error persists.
Here is my angular.json assets:

```
"assets": [
              { 
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/ngx-monaco-editor/assets/monaco",
                "output": "./assets/monaco/" 
              },
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"

            ]
```

This is in my app.module.ts:

```
MonacoEditorModule.forRoot()
```

This is in my component:

```
<ngx-monaco-editor [options]="editorOptions" [(ngModel)]="code"></ngx-monaco-editor>
```

But, I get this error, while trying to run the page:
GET http://localhost:4200/assets/monaco/vs/loader.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) ngx-monaco-editor.js:76

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing the Element on the html ?. I had a similar problem, And the way I solved it was adding this to the ngx-monaco.

```
<ngx-monaco-editor [options]="{ theme: 'vs-dark', language: 'mylang' }" (ngModelChange)="changes($event)" [(ngModel)]="_code" (init)="onInitEditor($event, 'largeEditor')">
</ngx-monaco-editor>
```

on the .ts

```
 async onInitEditor(editor, editorId) {
    this.editorRef[editorId] = editor;}
```

**EDIT**:
The library isself needs to be inialized its a property of the ngx-monaco-editor.